# Function calling procedure gives error "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I created a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAnnouncementID]() 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AnnouncementID int 
    EXEC @AnnouncementID = DB1.dbo.PROC_GetID 
    RETURN @AnnouncementID
END
GO
```

Then I tried to use `select dbo.GetAnnouncementID()` to get the return value, but the error message is:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

How to fix it?

Comment: you can't execute a sproc inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute a stored procedure from within a function. Your only option is to change it to an SP and modify your code to call an SP as follows:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetAnnouncementID]() 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @AnnouncementID int;
    EXEC @AnnouncementID = DB1.dbo.PROC_GetID;
    SELECT @AnnouncementID;

    RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Comment: @Burrell I must use function,not procedure,bucasue I use the value in merge.

Comment: You can't call an SP from within a function - there is no way around that other than to change your approach. You can return the results of an SP into a temp table and then merge that?

Comment: I hope you aren’t using a function with MERGE @Rhaegal unless you have a real good reason.